# Decorator pattern with decorators that can be implemented independently

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

I am writing a series of loggers. One will write to console, one to stdout, one to a proprietary file formart. At any point, i want any of these loggers to be able to be implemented and work on their own.

I had intended to use a decorator pattern to stack the loggers on top of each other, but i realize that the decorators are not intended to have the additional responsibilities stand on their own.

So my questions:
1) Is it acceptable for the responsibilities to be able to live on their own?
2) Is decorator pattern still the right path, or is there a pattern that better fits the problem i describe?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `decorators are not intended to have the additional responsibilities stand on their own`? Decorators should always be loosely coupled otherwise you lose the benefit of being able to apply them to different areas of your code.

Comment: In the examples i had been reading, it was described that the decorators were essentially add on responsibilities and not intended to be able to exist independently. I'd be happy to know that i was incorrect in that assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used pseudo C# - if you'd prefer another language, let me know.

To achieve this you firstly create an logging interface. Any objects doing logging will adhere to this:

```
public interface Logger
{
  void Log(string message);
}
```

Next you will need your decorator class which will wrap your logging functionality. This could also be abstract if you didn't want people instantiating it directly. It accepts a logger object and proxies all log messages to this:

```
public class LoggerDecorator : Logger 
{
  Logger logger;

  public LoggerDecorator(Logger logger) 
  {
    this.logger = logger;
  }

  public override void Log(string message) 
  {
    logger.log(message);
  }
}
```

It's possible to create standalone loggers:

```
public class StdoutLogger : Logger 
{
  public override void Log(string message) 
  {
    // Log message to stdout
  }
}
```

Or to "stack" loggers, simply wrap these using your `decorator`:

```
public class FileAndStdoutLogger : LoggerDecorator 
{
    public FileAndStdoutLogger(Logger logger) 
    {
      super(logger);
    }

    public void log(String message) 
    {
      logger.log(msg);

      // Log to file
    }
}
```

Then you can create standalone or decorated loggers:

```
var stdoutLogger = new StdoutLogger();
stdoutLogger.log("This will log only to stdout");

// Will output "This will log only to stdout" to stdout

var fileAndStdoutLogger = new FileAndStdoutLogger(new StdoutLogger());
fileAndStdoutLogger.log("This will log to file & stdout");

// Will output "This will log to file & stdout" to file and stdout
```

If you need further examples please let me know.

Comment: I'm in C++, but this is the path that i'd been going down. Any one of the loggers can live independently. if i haven't stacked the loggers, then either the the decorated logger contains a nullptr which i can eval against, or an empty logger that just does nothing.

Comment: Then I would say you're on the right path. But why do you think the decorated logger would container a null ref?

Comment: Because i don't necessarily want a 'base' logger. Since any of the loggers can be added in any order, they all have to be capable of injecting another logger instance.

Comment: You would have one implementation of `LoggerDecorator` for each type of logger then. Are you thinking about the case in which you would have only a single logger? In that case yes, you would need to check before calling `log` in your base/super class

Comment: Correct, it is the single logger case. i.e., i only care about writing to stdout and no where else.
I have it working at the moment, but i'm trying to improve on the (const char* content, ...) parameter list vs the c++11 variadic templates, which ive never used.

Comment: OK well an extra null check isn't going to hurt. Hope this helped!

Comment: It definitely did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I had intended to use a decorator pattern to stack the loggers on top
>   of each other

I do not think this is a good idea. Decorator pattern should work as some kind of [method call intercepcion](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/method-call-interception/184401947) or [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

That means executing some code before and/or after the body of a function is executed. Is nesting. I would not nest my loggers; I do not want to make a logger depends on other logger.

A good strategy is to create a generic logger and add listeners to it. Every listener has its own strategy to write the loged data. Just like [Trace and Debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/trace-listeners) in .NET enviroment. Then your generic logger just walk through list of added listener and call `log(message)` on each.

Then apply a decorator patter to compose decorated services for cross-cutting concerns like logging and security.

```
 Public Interface IMyService{
    int someAction();
}

Public Class MyService:IMyService{
    int someAction(){//impl goes here}
}

Public Class SecureMyService:IMyService{
    SecureMyService(IMyService innerService){
      inner = innerService;
    }
    int someAction(){
       if (!HasRights()) {throw authorizationException};
       return inner.someAction();
    }
}

Public Class LoggedMyService:IMyService{
    SecureMyService(IMyService innerService){
      inner = innerService;
    }
    int someAction(){
       logger.log("invoking some Action");
       return inner.someAction();
    }
}

//resolve decorated service. A DI container does wonderful things for decorator pattern ;)
IMyService GetService(){
    myService = new MyService();
    mySecuredService = new SecureMyService(myService);
    myLoggedAndSecuredService = new LoggedMyService(mySecuredService);
    return myLoggedAndSecuredService;
}
```